# Define Vector2 array in python

Tags: c#, ironpython

Hi trying to define a Vector2 array

```
Microsoft.Scripting.ArgumentTypeException: expected Array[Vector2], got list
```

This is the IronPython method:

```
public static bool InPoly(Vector2[] polygonArea)
{
    return MathHelper.IsPointInPoly(Me.Position, polygonArea);
}
```

This is how I'm trying to call it from python:

```
InPoly( [Vector2(163, 150), Vector2(134, 133), Vector2(96, 133), 
Vector2(68,148), Vector2(73,159), Vector2(95,183), Vector2(128,203), Vector2(139,203), Vector2(163,181)] )
```

Has to be on one line, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, in case anyone needs it.

```
InPoly(Array[Vector2]([Vector2(1, 2), Vector2(3,4)])
```